# Implement an internal abstract member

Tags: f#, mono

An abstract class, in this case System.Reflection.MethodBase, is requiring the implementation of the entire interface, which is fine. But it has this abstract member:

```
internal abstract ParameterInfo[] GetParametersInternal ();
```

and the F# compiler complains:

> No implementation was given for 'MethodBase.GetParametersInternal() :
>   ParameterInfo[]'

How can I implement this internal member, which I don't have access to? Or just ignore this and implement the public members.

If I do try to force the override:

```
override this.GetParametersInternal() = parameters |> List.toArray
```

I get:

> No abstract or interface member was found that corresponds to this
>   override.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably trying to build F# 3 with Type Providers.
This is a bug in Mono 3.0.6:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10884

It was fixed just two days ago, so just wait for 3.0.7, unless you'd like to compile Mono yourself.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Type Providers. And yes, it happened with 3.0.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override this memeber - internal members are only visible to types in the same assembly. `MethodBase` is defined in mscorlib, so `GetParametersInternal` is visible only to other types in that assembly, which your code isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lee said, you should not be able to override an internal member from another assembly.  I do not see any compiler errors when doing basic inheritance - below compiles fine:

```
type MyMethodBase() = 
    inherit System.Reflection.MethodBase()
    override this.Attributes with get () = failwith ""
    override this.GetMethodImplementationFlags() = failwith ""
    override this.GetParameters() = failwith ""
    override this.Invoke(obj, invokeAttr, binder, parameters, culture) = failwith ""
    override this.MethodHandle with get() = failwith ""
    override this.DeclaringType with get() = failwith ""
    override this.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, inh) = failwith ""
    override this.GetCustomAttributes(b) = failwith ""
    override this.IsDefined(attributeType, inh) = failwith ""
    override this.MemberType with get() = failwith ""
    override this.Name with get() = failwith ""
    override this.ReflectedType with get() = failwith ""
```